# Entity Framework Code-First Load Multiple Children From Single Table

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I am using EntityFramework 5.0 with Code-First. I have a POCO class Foo like this:

```
public class Bar
{
    public int FooID { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set; }

    public int OtherFooID { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo OtherFoo { get; set; }
}
```

In my DbContext, lazy loading is turned on. When I load the Foo from the context, property "Foo" is lazy loaded expected using FooID as the foreign key. However "OtherFoo" is NOT loaded, no matter how I try.

```
Foo f = bar.Foo;         // A proxy type, which loads in the data from the DB correctly
Foo f = bar.OtherFoo;    // is null, not lazily loaded
Foo f = context.Bars.Include("OtherFoo").First(...).OtherFoo;   // Still null
```

(In case it matters, I have a UserProfile table, and my model objects have CreatedByUser and LastModifiedByUser fields, neither of which work unless I rename one and its associated *ID field to "User")

Is there an attribute I can stick on these fields to tell Entity how to load them, or is there something I can set in the DbContext.OnModelBuilding method if I override it?

Comment: I would guess a mapping problem so that EF does not recognize `OtherFooID` as the foreign key for `OtherFoo`. `OtherFooID` is not nullable and the relationship would be *required*, i.e. there *must* be a related `OtherFoo` in the database (unless you have FK constraint enforcement turned off in the DB). Do you have any data annotations in `Bar` or `Foo` or mapping code with Fluent API? How does the `Foo` entity look like?

Comment: Making OtherFooID nullable does not change anything. The relationship is required, and the Foo record does exist. How do I tell EF that OtherFooID is the foreign key for OtherFoo? Is there an annotation I can use on the property, or is there something I can specify in the OnModelBuilding method of the DbContext?

Comment: `[ForeignKey("OtherFoo")]` on the `OtherFooID` property.

Comment: That `[ForeignKey]` attribute worked like a charm. Thanks. If you write that up as an answer, I'll select it and upvote it.

Comment: Cool that it worked :) I've written it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess a mapping problem so that EF does not recognize `OtherFooID` as the foreign key for `OtherFoo`. `OtherFooID` is not nullable and the relationship would be *required*, i.e. there *must* be a related `OtherFoo` in the database (unless you have FK constraint enforcement turned off in the DB).

You can specify the foreign key explicitly with data annotations ...

```
[ForeignKey("OtherFoo")]
public int OtherFooID { get; set; }
```

... or Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>()
    .HasRequired(b => b.OtherFoo)
    .WithMany() // add f => f.OtherBars here, if you have a collection in Foo
    .HasForeignKey(b => b.OtherFooID);
```

If you get an exception that "*multiple cascading delete paths are not allowed*" append

```
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

at the end of the Fluent mapping.